# batch rst2html conversion in a bash script

Tags: bash, batch

I have multiple .rst files in multiple folders and sub-folders on my Debian system.

How can I create a script that converts all the .rst files in html (with the rst2html command) and creates new folder and sub-folders keeping the original structure?

I tried this, but it fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find $directory -type f -name \*.rst)
do

rst2html "$i" "./html${i%.html}"

done
```

I have created the html folder, so I just want to put inside it all the converted .rst with the same tree-structure.

Terminal error is:

```
Unable to open destination file for writing:
  OutputError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './html./gdalogr/nearblack.rst'
```

Comment: I edited the question with an attempt..

Answer (score 1):

You shoud make the following changes to your script:

- Create the missing directories before calling `rst2html'
- Change the target path to include an extra `/` to allow for the source argument of `find` to start with a dot.

Here's a suggested solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1

for i in $(find $directory -type f -name \*.rst)
do
    RST_FILE="$i"
    HTML_FILE="./html/${i%.html}"
    HTML_DIR=$(dirname ${HTML_FILE})
    mkdir -p ${HTML_DIR}
    rst2html "$i" "$HTML_FILE"
done
```